Apply Pose Not Working
I'm trying to create a pose asset for my rig's hand and it isn't applying the pose asset. I'm able to pose the bones in pose mode and create a pose asset  in the Action Editor:

If I ALT+R to reset the bones and then apply the new pose asset, nothing happens:

Steps taken:

Selected all bones and switched to pose mode
Posed bones to desired position and in the Action Editor, clicked Create Pose Asset
Used ALT+R to reset bones to rest position
Clicked Apply Pose on the new pose asset

Expected behavior: the finger bones will re-position to the pose asset position.


pls add your blend file and pls tell us exactly the steps you do to add it. e.g. 1) select all bones in pose mode 2) object -> rigid body -> bake keyframes etc. (it's just an example) i think you got the idea. thx.

You are making it complicated, why are you not using one unique armature? Here you have one armature per phallange, no wonder you'll get lost...

I see, will the hand model and all fingers need to be a single mesh, as opposed to separate objects as they currently are?

You have 2 possibilities, either you join all them together, then parent With Empty Groups, and assign each part to the correct vertex group, or you keep them separate objects, select a phallange, shift select the armature, switch to Pose mode, select a bone and Ctrl P (parent to) > Bone. I think the first solution is the best because you have one unique object but you may prefer keeping them separate for some reason

All your phalanges are separate armatures, if you apply the pose it will only apply to the active bone, the last selected. Unless you have a good reason to keep separate armatures, you should better join them together as one armature.
As for the mesh objects, you have 2 possibilities: either you join all them together, then parent With Empty Groups, and assign each part to the correct vertex group, or you keep them as separate objects, select a phalanx, ⇧ Shift select the armature, switch to Pose mode, select a bone and ⎈ CtrlP (parent to) > Bone. I think the first solution is the best because you have one unique object, but you may prefer keeping them separate for some reason.
